# Button toggle in HTML or Controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following HTML below. I use AngularJS as framework and I will switch from on to off and back.
My question now would be how to switch the two buttons off and on - is it possible only to do it in html or do I need to handle it in the controller?

```
<div ng-click="vm.makeSomethingInController(scheduleResponseContent)" ng-show="vm.changeService"> 
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">OFF</button>
</div>
```

Function in the controller:

```
function setTriggerForLoadingOriginalSchedule(scheduleResponseContent) {
        vm.schedulepresenceonly = !vm.schedulepresenceonly;
        loadScheduleResponseOfUser(getCurrentDate(), '', vm.viewType, true, scheduleResponseContent.institutionUserConnectionId);
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-hide` and `ng-show`

like this

```
<button ng-show="schedulepresenceonly" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >ON</button>
<button ng-hide="schedulepresenceonly" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">OFF</button>
```

or just `ng-if`

Like this

```
<button ng-if="schedulepresenceonly" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >ON</button>
<button ng-if="!schedulepresenceonly" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">OFF</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely It depends On your **Problem domain** or ***What Problem Domain Says for you*** man for example , I have problem domain says When the user will click the **ON** button he/she get in to the different path(Page view) and if it is OFF button routes to different path(Page view).

Example,

In HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-ng-click="success()">ON</button>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-ng-click="failure()">OFF</button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.success = function(){
     <---Put Your Code--->
     console.log('Success Path');
     $location.url('/success');   
}

$scope.failure = function(){
     <---Put Your Code--->
     console.log('Failure Path');
     $location.url('/failure');   
}
```